# How my android app be authenticated automatically when deployed by AirWatch

Tags: android, single-sign-on, airwatch

I have a business app with some authorized REST.

After user install app via AirWatch Intelligent Hub. Can user use my app without login requirement? (use the credential from AirWatch Intelligent Hub)

- If yes, how can my app detect the credential to ignore the login?

Comment: You should tell us a bit more about authorization and REST in your app otherwise we can not help you. Show us your code please.

Comment: Currently, app support both basic and SSO (OAuth2):
- basic: 
     + app call a REST with usernamme + password to get an token. 
     + all business REST will use token for authentication
- OAuth2: support for integration into other system.

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: Sorry that i can not show code. Because, i don't see the relation between source code and the question, so i do not know which code do you want.

Comment: @tpv I think the code is relevant with the question for others to help. As i read the question above, first came in my mind was, what is the login need to be ignored? 2nd what rest api your app need to be authenticated? Firebase, AirWatch REST Api? Others does not know what you already code and where you stuck at? If the later, did you read the AirWatch REST Api document? Because in the document stated that there are 3 ways to authenticate in order to use AirWatch REST Api. At least portion of the code might give some hint to others help you.